# AVAnimator Assertion failure in -[AVMvidFrameDecoder advanceToFrame:] 'framebuffer num bytes'

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, video

I have dolwoaded the latest code from Github for AVAnimator library. I added the folders AVAnimator and LZMASDK in addition to AutoPropertyRelease.h and AutoPropertyRelease.m.

I am using the following code to play a video with alpha channel (adopted form another AVAnimator app examples):

```
 CGRect iPhoneExplosionRect = CGRectMake(0, -2, 640/2, 480/2);
CGRect iPadExplosionRect = CGRectMake(0, -5, 840, 630);

NSString *rgbResourceName = @"ExplosionAdjusted_rgb_CRF_30_24BPP.m4v";
NSString *alphaResourceName = @"ExplosionAdjusted_alpha_CRF_30_24BPP.m4v";

// Output filename

NSString *tmpFilename;
NSString *tmpPath;
tmpFilename = @"Explosion.mvid";
tmpPath = [AVFileUtil getTmpDirPath:tmpFilename];

// Set to TRUE to always decode from H.264

BOOL alwaysDecode = FALSE;

if (alwaysDecode && [AVFileUtil fileExists:tmpPath]) {
    BOOL worked = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tmpPath error:nil];
    NSAssert(worked, @"could not remove file %@", tmpPath);
}

// This loader will join 2 H.264 videos together into a single 32BPP .mvid

AVAssetJoinAlphaResourceLoader *resLoader = [AVAssetJoinAlphaResourceLoader aVAssetJoinAlphaResourceLoader];

resLoader.movieRGBFilename = rgbResourceName;
resLoader.movieAlphaFilename = alphaResourceName;
resLoader.outPath = tmpPath;
//resLoader.alwaysGenerateAdler = TRUE;

AVAnimatorMedia *media = [AVAnimatorMedia aVAnimatorMedia];
media.resourceLoader = resLoader;

self.expMedia = media;

// Frame decoder will read from generated .mvid file

AVMvidFrameDecoder *aVMvidFrameDecoder = [AVMvidFrameDecoder aVMvidFrameDecoder];
media.frameDecoder = aVMvidFrameDecoder;

// Create layer that video data will be directed into

CGRect expFrame;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    expFrame = iPhoneExplosionRect;
} else {
    expFrame = iPadExplosionRect;
}

CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.frame = expFrame;
}

if (FALSE) {
    layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
}

[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

AVAnimatorLayer *animatorLayer = [AVAnimatorLayer aVAnimatorLayer:layer];

self.expAnimatorLayer = animatorLayer;

// Finally connect the media object to the layer so that rendering will be
// sent to the layer.

[animatorLayer attachMedia:media];

//media.animatorRepeatCount = 3;
//media.animatorRepeatCount = 30;
//media.animatorRepeatCount = INT_MAX;

[media prepareToAnimate];
```

Once `prepareToAnimate` is hit the application fails at an assertion as described below

```
** Assertion failure in -[AVMvidFrameDecoder advanceToFrame:], /Users/user/Documents/.../AVAnimator/AVMvidFrameDecoder.m:844 

...*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'framebuffer num bytes'
```

Is it the architecture I am using (both 32 and 64 bit) causing it or something else?

I hope someone can put me on the right track

AF

Comment: Are you only seeing a problem on 64 bit hardware or does this assert get triggered on 32 bit hardware or in the 32 bit simulator?

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this assert and different ways it might be reproduced. I tried improperly setting the arch flags to include only 32 bit or only 64 bit code in the executable and tested on a 64 bit device and the simulator. I was not able to reproduce the problem and it is not clear how it could happen. To gather more information, I added an extra check that is compiled in either DEBUG or OPT mode when the framebuffer is allocated, could you pull the most recent version of AVAnimator from the github or grab the patch from [patch here](https://github.com/mdejong/AVAnimator/commit/a41078962c0b49b8a3c94275a89586124dc8f3be). Please make sure that none of the defines were modified in your version of the code and that you are using the most recent version of Xcode.

Comment: I was able to recreate this just now by downloading your AVSync demo and swapping the LS_C_Major_Open_4ths.mvid.7z file for a 1080p.mvid.7z file of my own.

My file was 1920x1080. It runs on the iPhone 6 simulator using xcode 7.1 but when I try to install it on my actual iPhone 6, it throws this same error after decoding the mvid.7z file:   

*** Assertion failure in -[AVMvidFrameDecoder advanceToFrame:], /AVSync-master/Classes/AVAnimator/AVMvidFrameDecoder.m:844
2015-10-24 16:03:12.759 AVSync[956:705766]

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'framebuffer num bytes : pagesize 16384 : addr 0x4701000 : addr mod pagesize 4096'


**** I had to add this as a second comment because the first comment was too long.

Comment: Could you run this cmd and verify what version appears in the .mvid file? $ mvidmoviemaker -info Huge.mvid | grep Version

Comment: Also, could you make sure to try the AVSync example Xcode project at this github link: https://github.com/mdejong/AVSync

Comment: Okay, I am convinced that I found the root of the problem. I just pushed changes to the github repos so that an old version 0 or version 1 .mvid cannot be opened. You will have to make sure your .mvid is version 2 by upgrading files after getting the most up to date version of MvidMovieMaker from the github repo.

Comment: Yes, your hunch was correct. From the new error message you added, it appears that my mvid was version 1, so I ran the upgrade command to get it to version 2. Now, it no longer throws the error above on iPhone 6. Thank you! But, I'm seeing very slow frame rate at 1080p resolution. Is that normal, or should the iPhone 6 be able to do 1080p at 30fps with this framework?

Comment: Could you just email me directly? The SO format is about dealing with one specific issue and that seems to have been addressed now.